# Why is squeezing not recommended after a needle prick?

Tags: blood-circulation, infection

I've read some interesting things about the risk of infection after a needle prick (30% - hepatitis B, 1.8% - hepatitis C and 0.3% - HIV), but I've also saw that the **local squeezing is not recommended**.

It's true that I've also found some articles that considered that there is no difference if you squeeze or not, but most of the articles I've read (in my native language) specified "Do not squeeze!!!". By squeezing I mean an act of extracting the blood by pushing the skin near the needle-prick.

Why?

Comment: If you've found relevant literature, don't just mention, cite!